# Transfering browser map from osm to google maps

Tags: google-maps, location, openstreetmap

it's quite hard to ask such a broad question specifically but what I basically want to do is having to browser tabs open – one with osm on it, the other displaying google maps. For a project I need the longitude / latitude information for each pixel from osm and get the related google maps pixel to it.

Is there any simple way to use maybe the html line to map the exact same data from osm to google maps so in the end I basically would have two tabs displaying the very same map, once in osm and once in google maps. Sorry if my phrasing causes any confusion.

The project is gonna be either in java or python, so maybe there is even something there already?

best,
Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Map Compare](http://tools.geofabrik.de/mc/) from Geofabrik. There are various similar services available.

Please note that you are not allowed to copy information between these two maps. Their licenses are not compatible.

Comment: thanks, that does look really promising. Concerning the information, it's really only the pixel to coordinate transfer i am doing, which shouldn't get me into trouble